# Using prototype to set an onclick event of a button?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, prototypejs, dom-events

I have this button:

```
<button id="check_button" name ="check_button" type="button" onclick="setLocation('...')">
    <span>check</span>
</button>
```

Now I know I can access it using `$('check_button')` for example. Is there a way to set the `setlocation` parameter with Prototype?

Answer (score 3):

```
function doButtonClick(event, element) {
  console.log('event');
  console.log('element');

  // here, `element` is a reference to the button you clicked.
  var elementId = element.identify();

  // I'm not sure what setLocation takes in as a parameter, but...
  setLocation(elementId);
}

$('check_button').on('click', 'button', doButtonClick);
```

Here are the docs for the `element.on`: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/on/

Which is really just a quick way of creating a new `Event.Handler`: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/

For sure check out that second doc link - super useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
$('check_button').observe('click',this.setLocation.bind(this,'...'));

setLocation: function(param)
{
alert(param);
}
```

In this way the param will be always what you pass. " bind " ia a vary powerfull method which holds that ability.